Resetting auth During Unit Testing
I am trying to run unit tests for a few portions of my Firebase web app, but I am running into issues with authentication. I have the mock authentication working (triggering onAuthStateChanged as expected). The problem I am having is that it seems the Firebase SDK is holding onto the auth object I pass in first, which makes sense other than I can't seem to sign out or reset the auth object in between tests.
My onAuthStateChanged observer:
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    console.log('onAuthStateChanged', auth, user);

    if (!user || (user && !user.currentUser.emailVerified)) {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    } else {
        await showInputs();
    }
});

My first test is:
const mockAuth = { currentUser: { uid: true, emailVerified: true } };

getAuth.mockReturnValue(mockAuth);
        
require('./register.js');

await onAuthStateChanged.mock.calls[0][1](mockAuth);

As expected, console.log prints
onAuthStateChanged
auth: { currentUser: { uid: true, emailVerified: true } }
user: { currentUser: { uid: true, emailVerified: true } }

But, on the next test mockAuth is set to
const mockAuth = { currentUser: { uid: true, emailVerified: false } };
                                                            ^^^^^

and console.log prints:
onAuthStateChanged
auth: { currentUser: { uid: true, emailVerified: true } }
user: { currentUser: { uid: true, emailVerified: false } }

Clearly, the SDK is holding onto the auth state, (again, this makes sense given I haven't logged out), but I have tried getAuth.mockReset(), signOut(getAuth()), getAuth.mockReturnValue(null), and a few others to no avail.
It isn't so much that I need to sign out, as much as I need to alter the auth object for other tests. These tests are merely checking authentication and are working as expected (they are simply easy examples to illustrate my problem).
I need to be able to add/update the auth.currentUser.email field for later tests. Since the SDK is hanging on to the auth object I initially provide (ignoring getAuth.mockReturnValue(mockAuth) on subsequent calls), I cannot test my code fully.
For this particular test, in my beforeEach call, I have:
getAuth.mockReset();

mockAuth = { currentUser: { uid: true, emailVerified: true, email: "johndoe@geemail.com" } };

getAuth.mockReturnValue(mockAuth);

But, when executed, auth.currentUser.email is undefined.
The problem function:
onValue(child(firebaseRef, `items`), items => {
    document.getElementById('itemList').innerHTML = '';

    // fill item list
    if (auth.currentUser) {
        items.forEach(i => {
            if (i.child('seller').val() === auth.currentUser.email && !i.hasChild('inactive')) {
                addItemToList(i);
            }
        });
    }
});

auth.currentUser.email is always undefined because when it is set in my first authentication test, I do not need nor provide an email property, but that is the auth object used for the entirety of the test run. If I change the mockAuth object and re-run the test, auth will have the new values (so maybe it doesn't have anything to do with 'signing out'??).
